# Unable to install Miniconda - Cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, installation, chromebook

I'm trying to install conda with [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) on my Chromebook using the Linux terminal. I'm on a 32-bit machine and have downloaded the 32-bit installer.

I've put the installer into my "Linux files" folder as per the guides I've been reading.

When trying to install, I get the below error.

```
Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86.sh: line 373: /opt/miniconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.15-h9bab390_6/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the 64-bit version?  My understanding is that depending on where you are looking the cpu info may be mis-reported.

Does your Chromebook have an ARM cpu?  There may be versions of Conda for ARM.  Also, there are many sites for running Python and using data science packages online.

Also, any reason why you downloaded the old Python 2.7 version instead of the one for Python 3?

Comment: I've tried both the 32 bit and 64 bit. Also was just trying the 2.7 version to see if that would work, the 3.7 gives me the same error. I think I'm just going to return it and get a windows machine.

Comment: My guess is whatever model you have runs an ARM processor. Anyway, you can install all the same packages using pip.  Conda is just for convenience.  Plus there are so many sites for doing data science online like this one: https://datalore.io/